# How can I get the free memory available on minions using on salt?

Tags: salt-stack

I am looking for a simple way to get information about memory usage, like free memory form the salt minions.

So far I know that the total memory can be listed using `salt '*' grains.items` but I don't even know how to list only just the total memory instead of the all grains data.

Second problem is that I don't know how to get the free memory returned.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So far, I was able to obtain this information using: `salt '*' cmd.run 'free -m -o | grep "Mem"'` -- maybe somebody else knows a better/easier way.

Answer (score 14):

To get the total memory, use *grains.item*, rather than *grains.items*:

```
salt '*' grains.item mem_total
```

Answer (score 10):

`salt targetminion status.meminfo`

If you are parsing this, change the output formatting:

`salt targetminion status.meminfo --out=json`

Comment: Then you can get the total and free memory with the 'jq' command line json parser:

`salt targetminion status.meminfo --out=json | jq '.targetminion.MemAvailable.value,.targetminion.MemTotal.value'`

will output for exmaple:
    "27123356"
    "32802164"

Comment: This is not supported on MacOS unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Better you use Grains for the same:
`salt '*' grains.item mem_total`

 Please refer: 
[Grains](http://intothesaltmine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapters/command-and-control/grains.html)

Answer (score -2):

`salt '*' disk.usage` should give you details about every partition in the minion. Details as in the available space, capacity usage and so on.